# jQuery delete parent onclick doesn't work for new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a form with a dynamic number of options. Deleting options works fine for those items that are existing from the start, but the items that are generated dynamically cannot be removed. Anyone have a clue?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kxr4C/

HTML:

```
<div class="options">
  <div><input type="text" name="option[]" value="Option A"> <a href="#" class="delete_option">Delete</a></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="option[]" value="Option B"> <a href="#" class="delete_option">Delete</a></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="option[]" value="Option C"> <a href="#" class="delete_option">Delete</a></div>
</div>
<a href="#" class="new_option">Add a new option</a>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery('a.new_option').click(function(){
  jQuery('div.options').append('<div><input type="text" name="option[]" value=""> <a href="#" class="delete_option">Delete</a></div>');
});

jQuery('a.delete_option').click(function(){
  jQuery(this).parent('div').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically created element:

```
jQuery('div.options').on('click', 'a.delete_option', function(){
  jQuery(this).parent('div').fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that works! I'll accept your answer as soon as it's allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
jQuery.on('click', 'a.delete_option', function () {
    jQuery(this).parent('div').fadeOut();
});
```

[Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score 0):

you should use .on method instead so that it delegates the event on new elements.

```
jQuery(document).on('click','a.delete_option',function(){
jQuery(this).parent('div').fadeOut();
});
```

here's a new fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/rjC6C/

Comment: While this is the correct syntax for delegate, `.on` on itself does not mean _delegate_. [`[...]As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.[...]`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) so `.on` it is the preferred way of adding _direct_ and _delegate_ listeners, only adding the selector as second argument makes it to a _delegate_.